# Status bar height increase in iphone

Tags: ios, ios8

[image]

Hello when my application is running at that time status bar height increase this problem occur only in ios8 otherwise all is working perfectly. So please help me to solve this problem. I am new in iPhone.

Comment: Only iOS 8, in iPhone 6 (or 6 Plus). Add launch screen to your project. Add new file -> User Interface - > Launch Screen. Then in your General field of your target, in the Launch Screen file field select it.

Comment: i add launch screen for iPhone6 with name "Default-667h@2x" 750X1334
and iPhone6+ "Default-667h@3x" 1241X2208

Comment: In iOS 8 (and iPhone6) only work on it, the launch screen is always a xib file. This file Default-667h@2x will be ignore.

Comment: @Onik if i am using launchscreen.xib and run application in iPhone6+ than UI component is mispalced.i dont understand why UI is misplaced?

Comment: @ParthMehta Welcome to iOS. Time to learn AutoLayouts. A good explanation here: http://mobileoop.com/how-to-use-auto-layout-in-xcode-6-for-ios-7-and-8-development. Also look at the Advanced techniques towards the end of the tutorial.

Comment: ParthMehta when you use launch screen (The new way). Each device will have its real dimension (in points). iPhone 5 (320x568) 6 (375x667) 6+ (414x736). As @instaable says you need use autoLayout, or another techniques in order your program work properly in all device. When you don`t use launch screen (old Apps), the size of all device is 320x568, with the zoom you know than change the status bar even.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can trey this.

Status bar height is, indeed, equals 20.0f points except following cases:

status bar has been hidden with setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation: method and its height equals 0.0f points;
as @Anton here pointed out, during an incoming call outside of Phone application or during sound recording session status bar height equals 40.0f points.
```

> [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height.

```
I found this in forum.
```